# Calculating the line integral going through the origin to some point

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am using the book, *"Introduction to Electrodynamics, by Griffith"* and it asks the following question.

> Calculate the line integral of the function $\vec{f}(\vec{v}) =
>  2x^3\hat{x} - yx \hat{y} + x^2\hat{z}$ from the origin to the point
>    $(1,1,1)$ by three different routes:
>
> $$a.) \ (0,0,0)\to (1,0,0)\to (1,1,0)\to (1,1,1)$$ $$b.) \ (0,0,0)\to
>  (0,0,1)\to (0,1,1)\to (1,1,1)$$ $$c.) \text{ The direct straight
>  line}$$

---

For $a$ I got the following:

$$\text{From } (0,0,0)\to (1,0,0) : y=z=0 \therefore \int f\cdot dl = \int^1_0 2x^3dx = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\text{From } (1,0,0)\to (1,1,0) : x=1, z=0, y: 0\to 1 \therefore \int f\cdot dl = \int^1_0 yxdy = \int^1_0 ydy =- \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\text{From } (1,1,0)\to (1,1,1) : x=y=1, z=0\to 1 \therefore \int f\cdot dl = \int^1_0 x^2dz = \int^1_0 dz =1$$

Thus $a = 1$.

---

For $b$ I got the following:

$$\text{From } (0,0,0)\to (0,0,1) : x=y=0, z: 0\to 1 \therefore \int f\cdot dl = \int^1_0 x^2dz = 0$$
$$\text{From } (0,0,1)\to (0,1,1) : x=0, z=1, y: 0\to 1 \therefore \int f\cdot dl = \int^1_0 yxdy = 0$$
$$\text{From } (0,1,1)\to (1,1,1) : z=y=1, x=0\to 1 \therefore \int f\cdot dl = \int^1_0 2x^3dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus $b = 1/2$.

---

For $c$ not sure what they mean by direct straight line? Also, will like to know if I my calculations for $a$ and $b$ are correct?

$$y=x, z=x, dz=dx, dy=dx$$
$$x=y=z \implies :0\to 1$$ thus the limits is from $0$ to $1$ $$\therefore \int^1_0 2x^3dx - x^2dx+x^2dx = \int^1_0 2x^3dx = 1/2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parts a and b, you need to add together the pieces of the trajectories

For part c, on the trajectory from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$ you have $x=y=z$ at any point, and $d\vec l$ pointing along $\hat x+\hat y+\hat z$:
$$d\vec l=|dl|\frac {1}{\sqrt3}(\hat x+\hat y+\hat z)$$
The limits of integration are from $0$ to $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: So a will equal 1 and b will equal 1/2. And still now sure about c? I have the following for c $$x=y=z \implies :0\to 1$$ thus the limits is from 0 to 1 and the answer I got is 1/2.

Comment: Note that there is an angle between the trajectory and each axis, so the dot product between the components of the function and $d \vec l$ are not $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$.

Comment: Hmm this is what I got,

$$y=x, z=x, dz=dx, dy=dx$$ $$\int v\cdot dl= 
 2x^3\hat{x} - yx \hat{y} + x^2\hat{z} =
 \int^1_0 2x^3dx - x^2dx+x^2dx = \int^1_0 2x^3dx = 1/2$$

Comment: It works because $\hat x \cdot d\vec l=dx$, $\hat y \cdot d\vec l=dy$, and $\hat z \cdot d\vec l=dz$, and you can just rename all the variables to $x$.